# Exponentiation of a modulo sum

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, exponentiation

Suppose a finite field in $F_p$, $p$ being a large prime and $g$ a generator of the field. Let two parts $A$ and $B$,with $A$ knowing a secret $a \in F_p$ and $B$ knowing another secret $b \in F_p$. Both of them want to compute: $$g^{ (a+b)\mod p} \mod p$$ without revealing their secret. Is this possible?

Comment: I guess $A$ could compute $g^{a+c}$ for some random $c$, hand that to $B$ who could compute $g^{a+b+c}$ and then multiply that by $g^{-c}$. Something like that anyway.

Comment: And how do you compute the $(a+b+c) \mod p$? If the modulo was not in the exponent you could simply compute $g^ag^b$.

Comment: Nobody needs  to compute $a+b+c$.  If $B$ is handed $g^{a+c}$, $B$ can just multiply it by $g^b$ to get $g^{a+b+c}\pmod p$.

Comment: The model I am thinking of is the old "income exchange" puzzle.  You have a bunch of people at a round table who all want to compute their average salary without revealing their own.  So...person one writes down $S_1+R_1$ where $S_1$ is their salary and $R_1$ is a random number known only to person one.  Person two adds $S_2+R_2$ and so on.  When it gets back to person one, they subtract $R_1$ and so on.  What's left is the sum of their salaries.

Comment: Yes, but i want to compute $g^(a+b \mod p) \mod p$, not $g^(a+b) \mod p$.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for formatting on this site.

Comment: Will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Trying to think of a way to use fermat and quotients myself.

Comment: It is so unnatural to want to add the exponents modulo $p$ that I won't even begin to think more about this one. The **only** thing to do at the **exponent** is arithmetic modulo $p-1$. I don't want to think about operations that are not naturally well defined.

Comment: Does this work: $A$ sends $(a+r)$ and $g^r$ to $B$, $r \in F_p$. $B$ computes $(g^{(a+b+r) \mod p}/g^r) \mod p$. Can $B$ find out $a$ this way?

Comment: What do you mean with "unnatural"? And why is modulo $p-1$ the only thing to do at the exponent? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Fiono, even if $a\equiv b\pmod p$ we usually do not have $g^a\equiv g^b\pmod p$. On the other hand, if $a\equiv b\pmod {p-1}$, we do get $g^a\equiv g^b\pmod p$ by Little Fermat.

Comment: Ok. What do you think about my idea above?

Comment: p-1 is the modulo of exponents to use in Fermat's little theorem. to convert between mod p and mod p-1 we need a quotient which isn't typically cared about in modular arithmetic.